# Apache VirtualHost Redirect Host + Path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I need to redirect all requests from http://example.com/app to http://app.example.com/. In VirtualHost I can only specify a ServerName as example.com. I only want requests from the host plus a specific path to be redirected to the domain with subdomain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com/app
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://app.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When you say redirect, do you mean proxy all request of http://example.com/app to http://app.example.com?  Or do you mean return a 301 Moved Permanently response to the browser with the http://app.example.com location?

Comment: Proxy the requests. The application infrastructure doesn't account for the subdomain so it uses /app instead, but on the front end I want the subdomain. In other words the application is redirecting to /app but I want it to appear as app.example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using apaches rewrite. Because I am using apache to forward requests to a tomcat application I do not have an .htaccess file which is where most tutorials tell you to place the rewrite. Turns out you can include it right in the virtualhost tag which is what I did. Here is a working sample.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com/app
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.example.com:8080/AppName/

# Rewrite all request from example.com/app to app.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/app/?(.*) http://app.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, this should do it:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPass /app/ http://app.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://app.example.com/
    RedirectMatch ^/app$    /app/
</VirtualHost>`

Since you probably already have a virtualhost for example.com, you should add the `Proxy*` lines to the existing config.